# DataProcessingFailed in Microsoft Custom Translator? Is there any log file?

Tags: microsoft-translator

I am using microsoft custom translator hub for translation.

Currently I am trying to train only one work for which I have created training file with 10,000 sentences for english and spanish. In training also I am using the same parallel files.

For some documents its working fine but for some it throws "DataProcessingFailed" error.

Is there any log file where I can see the error cause?

My Training file is as follows:

`The party has signed below
The party has signed below
The party has signed below
The party has signed below
The party has signed below
The party has signed below
The party has signed below
The party has signed below`

10,000 times this line

Spanish file

`La parte ha firmado a continuación
La parte ha firmado a continuación
La parte ha firmado a continuación
La parte ha firmado a continuación
La parte ha firmado a continuación
La parte ha firmado a continuación
La parte ha firmado a continuación`

10,000 times this line

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to submit 10000 *different* [sentences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/custom-translator/what-are-parallel-documents) to train a custom model using Custom Translator. Or you can use a dictionary if you want Microsoft Translator to translate an instance in a source phrase or sentence using the translation you provided in the [dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/custom-translator/what-is-dictionary).

Comment: Is it the case that Microsoft Translator considers unique sentences for modeling?